# Is my compiler incorrect?

Tags: c++, string, math, return

Whenever I run this in the compiler I get 1 returned to me. However, I've been told that this shouldn't return 1 and that my compiler is wrong and can't be trusted.

Is my friend right in that the compiler's I use are giving me the incorrect answer, or is this supposed to return 1?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    bool lol = "abc" < "abcd";
    std::cout << lol;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You compare pointers to those strings locations. Formally that's undefined behaviour. You probably want to use `std::strcmp()` or `std::string`s instead.

Comment: If your compiler returns `1`, there is something gone wrong during compilation. The compiler does not execute the source code, but … well … compiles it.

Answer (score 2):

The code has Undefined Behaviour, because it's using an oredering comparison operator on two pointers (the address of the string literal `"abc"` and that of the string literal `"abcd"`) which are not part of the same array. It can therefore do absolutely anything.

Comment: why is this pointer comparison? Isn't it supposed to be `string` comparison?

Comment: @It'scominghome But the code is doing `<`, which is not allowed cross-array.

Comment: @hiimdaosui String literals decay to pointers.